# Specify background colour when generating movie from images

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, png, transparency

I generate a video from png images using

```
ffmpeg -i visualization/%d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=500:trunc(ow/a/2)*2"  -pix_fmt yuv420p z.mov
```

and if images have transparencies, they become black. Can I somehow make them white?

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before running ffmpeg, use ImageMagick to "flatten" each PNG against white.

```
mogrify -background white -flatten visualization/*.png
```