# How to programatically insert a background color in an existing mp4?

Tags: android, video

I have a **mp4** file, where the video is having the **background** color as a solid color like white/green/blue. with that **background**, a video is recorded. I want to change the **background** color. Please let me know how to change the color **programatically** using **Android**.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense AT ALL. You say you are capturing a video with a background color? Can you tell me how is that even possible. Then you say you want to change the background programmatically using Android? Android is not program language, so changing a background using Android itself is impossible.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but asking a question like this is to broad, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: H.Brooks, sorry for my poor english. I mean to say, that I am recording a video of a person by keeping the background color as white/blue/green. You can assume the person is standing infront of the white board or any wall whose color i want to change later. Is it possible? I am saying using Android doesn't mean only android will do that job. There are other libraries like ffmpeg or some similar kind, which I should be able to take help. If anyone who have come across such requirement, any solution will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [ImageMagick](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick) and [FFMPEG](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android).

First you will have to get all the frames from the video using `FFMPEG` using something like:

```
ffmpeg -i "inputFile.mp4" "frames/out-%03d
```

Then using `ImageMagic` you can flatten each against the color you want like:

```
mogrify -background green -flatten visualization/*.png
```

Then you will have to use `FFMPEG` again to create a `video/.mp4` file again using something like:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' \
-c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

**Disclaimer:**

This is just a guideline to get you started and to give you a idea of how you can achieve what it is you asked for. More research should be done as this is a simple question to answer.

---

Here are some links that I found helpful:

- [using ImageMagic to flatten image with specific background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21723343/5550161)
- [Using FFMPEG to get all frames from video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786929/5550161)
- [Creating a video with FFMPEG using images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966617/5550161)